# What establishes "kevi'ut" in terms of "makom kavu'ah" (established seat in shul)?

Tags: synagogue, makom-kavuah

The *Tur* in [Orach Chayim 90](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tur%2C_Orach_Chaim.90.1?lang=he), quoting an Amora in *B'rachos*, says that one should have a fixed location that he always davens, including within a shul. It is often called *makom kavu'ah*. (I'll abbreviate it as M.K.)

> ויקבע מקום לתפלתו שלא ישנהו אם לא לצורך גדול (ס"א לצורך מצוה) דאמר רב הונא כל הקובע מקום לתפלתו אלהי אברהם בעזרו ואין די לו במה שיקבע לו ב"ה להתפלל בה תדיר אלא **גם בב"ה שקובע בה צריך שיהיה מקומו קבוע** וידוע ולא ישב היום כאן ולמחר במקום אחר דהכי אתמר בירושלמי א"ר תנחום בר חייא צריך אדם לייחד לו מקום בב"ה שנאמר ויהי דוד בא עד הראש אשר ישתחוה שם השתחו' לא נאמר אלא ישתחו' משמע שהיה תדיר משתחוה שם

Is there a fixed amount of time to establish a place as a M.K.? How long / often is this? And, does this amount of time need to be contiguous? Can one lose his *kevi'ut* if he is not there for a while? If so, how long?

**Related:** Some shuls sell the seats, such as for High Holidays. I assume, then that the M.K. status lasts for the duration of the holidays, only. But, let's say seats are sold for the entire year, and that payment is due by a specific date. If a person is late paying but still intends to keep his seat, has he lost his M.K. by not paying, or is his intent to pay still valid, and for how long?

Actual occurrence:

My shul has a "chapel" which is used for "daily" davening, and a larger shul used only on Shabbat and Yom Tov. I've been attending the shul upstairs weekly for many years. After about a year of deveining in the same spot, one week someone asks me to vacate my seat because he claims that it is **his** M.K. Apparently, he **used** to daven there years ago, went to another shul, and decided to return. If someone is gone for a long time, doesn't he lose that spot?

Comment: M.B. says within 4 amos is counted as makom kavua because it's impossible otherwise.

Comment: @user6591 That defines the physical space of M.K. That's not what I'm asking.

Comment: +1 in any case. I'm pretty sure the rishonim (Rosh?) Used laws of chazzaka for shul seats.

Comment: I know that's not what you are asking. But it would answer the problem. At least according to halacha.

Comment: I don't know why there need to be formal rules about this. We all know what it means to have a spot that you use regularly and feel comfortable in. If moving 6 inches over in your synagogue setting makes you feel displaced thats not good, and if moving 10 ft over still feels the same that's fine. (If you leave for 20 years and come back you'll naturally go back to your spot, and if someone else also views it as their spot then you can flip a coin or something Choshen-Mishpat-y. The right to use the spot and the 'obligation' to pray in a regular location aren't the same thing.)

Comment: in siman 90 m.b. {ס} מקום קבוע - ותוך ד"א חשוב מקום אחד דא"א לצמצם:

Comment: The source(s) you cite only instruct a person how to achieve best results when praying, so the soonest one could implement the instruction given would be the second time they show up to a place they've prayed before. Further, one might infer that if one has prayed in one spot 3 times and another one 4 times and now has to choose between them, the 4-time one would be preferable.